# Application of inverse function theorem on map between manifolds

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I  am reading Milnor's Topology from the differentiable viewpoint and I came across the following:
Let $f: M\rightarrow N$ be a smooth map between manifolds of the same dimension. Let $x \in M$ be a regular point.

> It follows from inverse function theorem that $f$ maps a neighbourhood of $x$ in $M$ diffeomorphically onto an open set in $N$.

Here should we assume $x \in M$ and $y=f(x)\in N$ to not to be on the boundary to have an open neighbourhood around them in the first place?

Comment: The definition of a regular point ensure the existence of such a neighborhood.

Comment: Oh, so such $x$ can't be a boundary point right?

Comment: Yes. Being a regular point ensures there exists some small open neighborhood of $x$ which makes it an interior point and therefore not a boundary point.